# display update and cancel button after clicking edit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

we have marketplace site, where each seller/vendor have their own account. they can see list of products. sku ,qty in their account.

now its displaying like this : image 1 =http://prnt.sc/8wm25g

if i click on cancel button , than its displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/8wm2fv

what i need is :

a)if we click on edit button, than only "Update" & "cancel" button should visible and "Edit" button should hide.

b)Later if we click on "cancel" button, than "Update & cancel" button should hide and "Edit" button should visible.

```
<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>
      <input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" name = "qty" value = "<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>



    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
            <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
        </span>  

        <br/>
        <button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
            <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
        </button>

        <button id="reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;">
            <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
        </button>

    <script type = "text/javascript" >

            var $wk_jq = jQuery.noConflict();

            function hideReset(product_id) {
                var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
                var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
                var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;

                $wk_jq(editLink).show();
                $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
                $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
            }
             function showField(product_id)
            {
                var qtyId = '#qty_'+ product_id;

                var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
                var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
                var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;

                $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

                $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
                $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
                $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

                $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();


            }
            function updateField(product_id)
            {
                var qtyId = '#qty_'+ product_id;

                var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
                var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
                var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;
            var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateField/')?>';

                $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

                $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
                $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
                $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

                $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();

                new Ajax.Request(url, {
                    method: 'post',
                    parameters: {id: product_id, qty: $qty},
            onComplete: function (transport) {


                    alert(transport.responseText);
            $wk_jq(qtyId).setValue($qty);

                }
                });
            }
```

Comment: From what I see, it should work. Let me take a look in Fiddle and get back.

Comment: You don't really say what the problem is, but I see that your selector for `#reset_button` is missing the underscore before the id -- in the markup, you use `reset_button_10`, for example, but your code here would try to use `reset_button10`, see the missing underscore? Other than that, it isn't clear what you're asking. I assume something isn't working the way you want it to, but you haven't told us what isn't working, or how you've tried to address it. Voting to close. If you can edit to improve the question, I'll retract my vote.

Comment: What is the generated code? I have this working fine here for me. Show what the actual generated page is. Also, what is in your console?

Comment: @frostymarvelous this is the complete file = http://pastebin.com/VVg0krmX above code in question is part of this file

Comment: @ChrisBaker I updated the question

Comment: @ChrisBaker please open this link : http://2.kidsdial.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovLzIua2lkc2RpYWwuY29tLz9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/

login with 

email : kidsdial2@gmail.com
pw : kidsdial2

than click on this link : 

http://2.kidsdial.com/index.php/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

there you can see"Qty" column ,than please check the question again

Comment: Got it. Check my answer.

Comment: like @ChrisBaker said, you are missing an underscore for the reset button. Funny how Chris and I both chose 10 as our example ID.

Comment: ya you are right @frostymarvelous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking at it, there are a few issues I noted.
Rather than doing it exactly as you wanted, I made some changes.

1. Update button should not be showing at start since there is nothing to update.
2. Cancel should only be shown when editing.
3. Update button should be disabled during ajax request.

Find the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/g1v9x1bt/
and the full code below. See if it helps you out.

```
So after looking at it, there are a few issues I noted.
```

Rather than doing it exactly as you wanted, I made some changes.

1. Update button should not be showing at start since there is nothing to update.
2. Cancel should only be shown when editing.
3. Update button should be disabled during ajax request.

Find the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/g1v9x1bt/
and the full code below. See if it helps you out.

```
    <span id="qty_span_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?></span>
      <input type="text" id="qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" name="qty" value="<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" style="display:none"/>


    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
            <img width="25" onclick="showField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit') ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit') ?>"/>
        </span>  

        <br/>
        <button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>');" style="display:none" >
            <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
        </button>

        <button id="reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>');" style="display:none">
            <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
        </button>




    <script>
        var $wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();

        function hideReset(product_id) {
            var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
        }

        function showField(product_id)
        {
            var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;
        }

        function updateField(product_id)
        {
            var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;

            var qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();

            var $updateButton = $wk_jq("#update_button_"+ product_id);


            //disable it after start
            $updateButton.prop('disabled', true);

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {id: product_id, qty: qty},
                onComplete: function (transport) {
                    $wk_jq('#qty_span_' + product_id).text(qty);
                    hideReset(product_id);
                    $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);
                    alert(transport.responseText);

                    $wk_jq(qtyId).setValue($qty);
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: i updated your code, please check here : http://2.kidsdial.com/index.php/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/ its working only for first product

Comment: first it showing real quantity [200] what we are editing now is not real quantity.
its not saving in database, please check....

Comment: Okay, it wasn't an exact replacement for your code. It is a guide for you to follow and apply to your code. If you watch closely, I removed the PHP code. And the ajax code is not valid ajax just a simulation.

Comment: sorry, i missed the code, everything is working fine, but now its not saving in database, thats it, please help for this.....

Comment: when we edit, its displaying in seller account, but in database its not saving....

Comment: can you use my ajax code and help me to save in database?

Comment: I updated it to use your ajax code. That should not have been an issue for you at all.

Comment: Compare the code you posted and what I posted side by side. I don't have access to your development server so I removed all the php. Please check it and ensure you put all of it back. This is a guide not a replacement.

Comment: its working only for one product, okay i will check it and even its not saving in database, but i i will try.....

Comment: i tried i  am not getting ,can you please help me to save in database and editing should work for all products

Comment: Can I suggest, rather than saying updated when the value updates, don't. You are already using an optimistic feedback so when the user clicks update and the value changes, the user assumes it updated fine. Instead, let the user know if it fails so they can try again.

Comment: please help me here :  please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650823/convert-vertical-menu-to-horizontal-menu-using-css?noredirect=1#comment55075519_33650823